# How to set a specific function to every widget while using loops in tkinter from Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, lambda, tkinter, mouseevent

I'm exploring tkinter from Python 3 and I have a problem with using loops to create widgets containing functions. I have this code:

```
from tkinter import *

def test(no, button_name, event=None):
    def callback():
        print(button_name)
    return callback

root = Tk()
list_of_buttons = 'Button 1, Button 2, Button 3, Button 4, Button 5'.split(', ')
for no, i in enumerate(list_of_buttons):
    list_of_buttons[no] = Button(root, text=i, command=test(no=no, button_name=i))
    list_of_buttons[no].grid(row=no, column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

This code Works good, and the result is when you press each button, it prints its's own name. But, I think buttons are ugly, even with ttk, so I am planning to make some customized screen, with labels and images instead of buttons. Then I tried to change the Button widget to a Label, in this way:

```
list_of_buttons[no] = Label(root, text=i)
list_of_buttons[no].bind('<Button-1>', test(no=no, button_name=i))
```

Then an error appears:

> TypeError: callback() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

I tired to fixed using lambda but when i use it, when I press the label it just doesn't work:

```
list_of_buttons[no].bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: test(no=no, button_name=i))
```

I also tried calling the callback function like this:

```
return callback()
```

But this only print 'Button 5'. Is there any way to do the same with the labels that needs event bindings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your callback def to:

```
def callback(event=None):
    print(button_name)
```

This is because the callback that tkinter calls is actually the `callback` function, not the `test` function. Test function does not need `event=None`.